# Mysterious errors when using tensorflow.add

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and need help with the problem below in my console. It seems that I am able to import tensorflow, yet `tf.add(3,5)` returns:

> `cannot open shared object. No such file or directory`.

[image: The Error I am getting]

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please post your errors using the code block instead of images, for more info please read : (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also ensure you give us a Minimal reproduceable example, read about it here: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ÂnTạVăn Check SammyJ comment above for guidelines on writing questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, the best bet is to make sure both tensorflow and python are updated to latest version. I might try uninstalling and reinstalling python and/or some libraries, or checking the ROOT directory: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262063/how-to-find-python-installation-directory-on-ubuntu . Good luck!